# Are Star City and Central City the same city?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, arrow

There is Star City and Starling City but I've heard the Flash's home referred to as Central City and I know it shouldn't be this confusing but it is. Are Star City and Central City the same city?

Answer (score 8):

## No

They are two different places. Indeed, the Flash is sometimes shown travelling betwen them.

[**Star City**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_City_(comics)) (previously called Starling City) is the home of the Green Arrow.

[**Central City**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_City_(DC_Comics)) is, and always has been the origin city of The Flash in the TV Show and the DC Comics

Answer (score 4):

In the Arrowverse (TV series) it is (Green) Arrow's hometown that starts out as Starling City, and then becomes Star City in the forth season.
(Ref [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_City_(comics))).

Whereas Central City has long been the hometown of the Flash.
(Ref [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_City_(DC_Comics))).